# ListView.builder não atualiza ao retirar um elemento da lista, mas ao adicionar sim

Tags: flutter, dart

Eu tenho um future builder que recebe uma lista, e logo retorna uma coluna com uma ListView.builder() e um botao abaixo, ao usar o botao para adicionar um elemento a lista atualiza com sucesso, agora ao usar um botao que se encontra dentro do ListTile para excluir o elemento, o elemento é excluido porém a lista não atualiza. Segue um exemplo do que seria.

```
Dialog(
 FutureBuilder(
  future: getChapters(),
  builder (context, snapshot) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount:snapshot.data.length,
            builder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text("teste");
                trailing: InkWell(
                  child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  onTap: (){
                    deleteChapter();
                    setState((){});
                  }
                ),
              );
            }
          )
        ),
        RaisedButton() {   
          onPressed: () {
            addChapter();
            setState((){});   
          }
        }
      ]
    );
  }
 )
)
```

Ao eliminar um elemento da lista, ela só atualiza fechando e abrindo o widget.

Comment: Seria bom analisar um código completo nesse caso, se não precisamos ficar adivinhando o que 'deleteChapter()' faz, o 'FutureBuilder' está dentro do que, etc..

Comment: Sim, tambem acho, é que é bem grandinho, eu contornei esse problema, mas não ficou resolvido.

Comment: Ai que tá, o ideal seria criar um novo projeto e 'replicar' apenas o erro que vc está com dúvida do comportamento, aí compartilhar esse código. O projeto inteiro acaba dificultando tbm a análise de coisa desnecessária ao invés de focar no erro. Já fiz muito isso e na maioria das vezes eu mesmo encontro o problema ao tentar isolar o erro em outro projeto.

Comment: Cara, uma dica é quando você for utilizar o ` setState()` coloque dentro dele o método que deseja executar, não fora, seguindo o teu exemplo faça: `setState((){deleteChapter();});`

Comment: Informe o que existe dentro do método `deleteChapter()` que assim podemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Editei o exemplo, sou novo nas perguntas por isso não postei o problema bem especificado. O deleteChapter() altera a lista da mesma maneira que o addChapter(), só que claro, uma adiciona um elemento e a outra retira, e depois o banco de dados é atualizado com a nova lista. O botao que adiciona está fora do FutureBuilder() e ele atualiza o Dialog() com sucesso depois de adicionar, agora o botao que esta no ListTile() retira um elemento da lista, mas só é possível ver a alteração fechando e abrindo o Dialog().

Comment: Em poucas palavras, os processos de adicionar e remover são praticamente iguais, porém ao remover um elemento da lista  usando um botão dentro do listTile a tela não atualiza, mas ela altera a lista com sucesso.

Comment: @NelsonThiago Edite sua pergunta e adicione o código de dentro do seu método `deleteChapter()` e `addChapter()` daí conseguimos entender melhor a situação.

Comment: Editei o post. realmente o problema era devido a função deleteChapter() ser async

Comment: @NelsonThiago como é sua primeira vez aqui e como nossa ajuda não foi tão bem aceita por você para melhorar a sua pergunta, reserva um tempinho seu para ler isso aqui:[Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel?cb=1)... Isso vai nos ajudar a te ajudar em um futuro próximo.

Comment: Na verdade eu só não melhorei a pergunta por que estava sem tempo, se tivesse melhorado provavelmente vocês haviam encontrado o problema bem antes que eu.

Comment: @NelsonThiago Se conseguiu resolver o problema, a solução deve ser publicada na área de respostas, não como edição na pergunta. Na pergunta só deve ficar o que é relacionado à própria pergunta. Leia [Responder sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422/5878). Já reverti a edição que fez adicionando a resposta na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Adiciona uma UniqueKey no seu ListView que deve funcionar. Quando o flutter está rebuildando o seu Widget ele faz a comparação por tipo pra saber se o widget deve ser rebuildado ou não, como tinha um ListView antes e depois continua o mesmo ListView na mesma posição o flutter acha que não deve rebuildar esse cara (mesmo os dados deles tendo sido modificados), então pra ajudar o flutter nesse trabalho você adiciona uma UniqueKey que vai ser diferente toda vida.

Comment: Como ele está apenas incluindo e removendo itens da lista, não é necessário a utilização de `Keys`, isso poderia até custar um pouco mais de processamento. E se possível quando responder à pergunta, coloque algum exemplo prático, como por exemplo de onde por essa `UniqueKey`.

Comment: Não entendi porque você tá dizendo que não é necessária. É um dos principais usos de keys...

Comment: Concordo que é um dos principais usos, só digo que não é necessário o uso nesse contexto dele. Se ele for fazer um esquema para excluir e restaurar o item ai sim seria necessário o uso, mas como ele está apenas incluindo/excluindo não se faz necessário.